# Microsoft Bot Framework Language translate

Tags: botframework

I am quite new to the Microsoft Bot Framework, I would like to use BOT to translate user input to the language user specifies, how to get started with this? please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

In Bot Builder V4,
you can use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link to the official answer regarding this https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1156